# Stripping a string and getting start index and end index

Tags: python, strip

Is there any straightforward way in Python to strip a string and get the start index and the end index?

Example: Given the string `'  hello world!   '`, I want to the stripped string `'hello world!'` As well as the start index `2` and the and index `14`.

`'  hello world!   '.strip()` only returns the stripped string.

I could write a function:

```
def strip(str):
    '''
    Take a string as input.
    Return the stripped string as well as the start index and end index.
    Example: '  hello world!   '  --> ('hello world!', 2, 14)
    The function isn't computationally efficient as it does more than one pass on the string.
    '''
    str_stripped = str.strip()
    index_start = str.find(str_stripped)
    index_end = index_start + len(str_stripped)
    return str_stripped, index_start, index_end

def main():
    str = '  hello world!   '
    str_stripped, index_start, index_end = strip(str)
    print('index_start: {0}\tindex_end: {1}'.format(index_start, index_end))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but I wonder whether Python or one popular library provides any built-in way to do so.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way. Your code is really concise, it's really just the three lines of `str_stripped = str.strip()`, `index_start = str.find(str_stripped)`, and `index_end = index_start + len(str_stripped)`. All the rest is superfluous.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: It's concise but as the comments say he's doing more than one pass on the string. Of course you could code a `strip()` function that returns the desired output while doing just one pass, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option (probably not the most straight-forward) would be to do it with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '  hello world!   '
>>> match = re.search(r"^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$", s)
>>> match.group(1), match.start(1), match.end(1)
('hello world!', 2, 14)
```

where in `^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$` pattern:

- `^` is a beginning of a string
- `\s*` zero or more space characters
- `(\S.*?)` is a capturing group that would capture a non-space character followed by any characters any number of times in a *[non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) fashion*
- `$` is an end of a string

Comment: This won't work correctly if there is no whitespace to be stripped. Using `'\s*'` instead should help

Comment: Was going to post something similar,  it seems to actually be the fastest way on the tests I did but only if you compile first otherwise it is quite a bit slower than the OP's own code

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to do this is by invoking `lstrip` and `rstrip` separately.  For example:

```
s = '  hello world!   '
s2 = s.lstrip()
s3 = s2.rstrip()
ix = len(s) - len(s2)
ix2 = len(s3) + ix
```

This gives:

```
>>> s3
'hello world!'
>>> ix
2
>>> ix2
14
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have the necessary methods to accomplish this task. `strip`, `find` and `len` are all you need.

```
s = '  hello world!   '
s1 = s.strip()
first_index = s.find(s1)
end_index = first_index + len(s1) - 1
```